# Dictionary extension with generics, error: "type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: swift

In adding a keyPath-based extension for Dictionary that takes an autoclosure as a parameter won't compile with a "`Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`" error.

The first method compiles fine, not sure how to fix the 2nd's compiler error.

Any tips?

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any {
    public func value<T>(for key: Key, default defaultExpression: @autoclosure () -> T) -> T {
        return (self[key] as? T) ?? defaultExpression()
    }

    public func value<T>(forKeyPath keypath: Key, default defaultExpression: @autoclosure () -> T) -> T {
        return (self.value(forKeyPath: keypath) as? T) ?? defaultExpression()
    }
}
```

Comment: What method are you trying to call when you say `self.value(forKeyPath: keypath)`? There is no such method.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416468-value, maybe Dictionary isn't an NSObject?

Comment: No, the Swift `Dictionary` is a struct, and therefore cannot inherit anything.

Comment: Ah, so "keypath" in your question refers to an objective-C key path. I totally thought you meant a Swift `KeyPath`, and was wondering why you were using `String` and not the `KeyPath` type instead. Now that you know `Dictionary` is not an `NSObject`, it doesn't make sense to do this anymore, does it?